# How to enable EGLFS i.Mx6 QPA for Qt on IMX6Q?

Tags: qt, buildroot, imx6, eglfs

I am cross compiling Qt with Buildroot and GCC Linaro for an IMX6Q target.

I would like to use eglfs platform plugin but i am confused about the list of associated backends available.

```
QPA backends:
  DirectFB ............................... no
  EGLFS .................................. yes
  EGLFS details:
    EGLFS OpenWFD ........................ no
    EGLFS i.Mx6 .......................... no
    EGLFS i.Mx6 Wayland .................. no
    EGLFS RCAR ........................... no
    EGLFS EGLDevice ...................... yes
    EGLFS GBM ............................ yes
    EGLFS Mali ........................... no
    EGLFS Raspberry Pi ................... no
    EGL on X11 ........................... no
    LinuxFB ................................ no
    VNC .................................... yes
    Mir client ............................. no
```

I guess that the EGLFS i.Mx6 is best suited for IMX6Q but how is it possible to activate this option instead of the EGLDevice or GBM ?

I have configured Qt with `-device linux-imx6-g++` ( using buildroot Custom configuration options)  but it does not change anything and i don't see any other options so far.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable BR2_PACKAGE_IMX_GPU_VIV, which will provide the OpenGL implementation for i.MX6.

Comment: Works great. Thanks.